# Can I affect CSS rule order?

Tags: css

Here is a recreation of a problem i ran into last week.
I have 3 boxes and want to shift 2 of them left so they fit into its parent box. I can shift them successfully but CSS fully ignores that they can fit into the width and puts the last box in a new line which completely ruins the look. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6uBk/1/) I see the problem with firefox 11 and chrome 18. How can i affect the css so the 3 boxes will fit in the line since it obviously can when doing the left shift.

The html (the second part is just to see the shift is working vs if there was no shift.)

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
</div>


<div class="A2">
    <div class="B2"></div>
    <div class="C2"></div>
    <div class="D2"></div>
</div>
```

The css

```
.A { width: 290px; height:200px; background-color: red; }
.B, .C, .D { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.B, .D { background-color: green;}
.C { width: 100px; background-color: blue; }
.A div { float: left; }
.C, .D { position:relative; left: -50px; }


.A2 { width: 290px; height:200px; background-color: red; }
.B2, .C2, .D2 { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.B2, .D2 { background-color: green;}
.C2 { width: 100px; background-color: blue; }
.A2 div { float: left; }
```

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking. What is the result you want? Why do you need to "shift 2 of them left so they fit into its parent box", shouldn't they already "fit" in the parent box?

Comment: @WesleyMurch the parent is <300px, the 3 boxes are 100px each thus 300px wide cannot fit in <300px wide. I want them to fit in the line bc they can after the left shift

Comment: A screenshot of the displayed behavior and the desired behavior side-by-side would be helpful here.

Comment: @SurrealDreams: How about the working demo that i linked when i posted the question...

Comment: One question, why don't simply set: `.C, .D { width:50px; }` ?

Comment: @Zuul: They are in reality images and that would affect the scale.

Comment: @acidzombie24: We are trying to help you out, but your are leaving out some important details! Using negative margins, position:absolute on tons of elements, etc is a very hacky way of solving the issue! I suggest you add a more detailed information  to your question to allow a solid solution! (just saying)

Comment: @Zuul: Ok but the thing is i don't want a solution on MY problem. I want to know why THIS didnt work and something adequate to solve it. Sure i could scale things and other solutions but if i cant in a different problem (like my real one which uses images) i wouldnt know what to do (i dislike scaling images) or why i cant shift boxes to the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them all to fit on one line, you can use negative margins.

You have 10px of extra space to count for, so you might want to divide as evenly as possible, something like this ( a bit awkward with 3 elements):

```
.B{ margin-left: -3px; }
.C{ margin-left: -3px; }
.D{ margin-left: -4px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M6uBk/15/

There are many other ways to do it or you can adjust these number any way so they add up to 10, it just depends on how much of which elements you want showing since it can't possibly all fit within the container.

Comment: Thats brilliant! Thanks (i just simply did -50px left-margin  http://jsfiddle.net/M6uBk/17/)

Comment: Still not clear why you don't just adjust one of the widths. Are these really images, and not divs?

Comment: @acidzombie24 if it's images, it's even better to use the correct width and let the images scale to 100% on hover.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Here's another trick that might interest you: http://jsfiddle.net/M6uBk/18/ Just set any width on the inner div that will fit all the images.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: interesting. Why doesn't it work when i make .A overflow hidden http://jsfiddle.net/M6uBk/19/ and does work when if i move it into container (like your example). Strange.

Comment: Because you need the parent element of the 3 divs to be wide enough.

Answer (score 6):

well 3x100px > 290px, right? So it's no wonder the 3rd box breaks onto the newline.

You need to keep in mind, that `position:relative` **keeps the original space of the element** occupied. That's why the 3 boxes don't fit although you shift 2boxes 50px to the left.

edit:

Try to use `position:absolute` - it takes the elements out of the document-flow (this is not "compatible" with float though). Other than that you need to adjust the width of the child elements to fit the with of the parent or vice versa.

keep in mind, that by using absolute positioning or negative margins, parts of your content gets clipped. It's better to use correct dimensions, so everything fits well.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M6uBk/16/)

Comment: +1, thats what i assumed and my question is if i can affect the css rules/order so they WILL fit in the same line

Comment: I changed relative to absolute and now i only see 1 box.  http://jsfiddle.net/M6uBk/12/

Comment: @acidzombie24, didn't expressed myself properly, I was saying that I was setting up a Fiddle with the solution, based on your Fiddle's problem :)

Comment: @acidzombie24 see my edited fiddle. you need to specify a position for every div when using absolute positioning.

Comment: I need to hand write it for every element!?! This is insanity! (My real code uses more). I guess if it works it works. I guess i can generate css with html. Accepted. and why does css have to suck :(

Comment: @WesleyMurch You got it! They are in reality images and on mouse over i change the z-order so the image will be above other images :)

Comment: @acidzombie24 the simplest solution would simply be to fit either the childrens width to the parent or vice versa. That is much cleaner then absolute positioning or negative margins since this messes with the content.

Comment: @acidzombie24 If you use images, just use `%` to let them fit the the parent container, then on hover scale them to their original dimensions.